# How to create pullup and pulldown effect in web?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are creating mobile application and need to create some sort of "android loading" effect. I've tried to draw, because it's difficult to explain.

[image: pull back bounce]

1. User is at the end of scroll up
2. User keeps scrolling (swiping page up) and should see an empty space (marked yellow)
3. User releases finger and table is bouncing back down, hiding empty space.

All we know how it works in native enviroment, but what would be the best technique to reproduce the same in web? Thanks in advance for any advise.

EDIT: for those who think that question is too broad. I dont need code in answer, I want to get an idea on what whould be the best approach to solve this.

Comment: This is too broad. Try it yourself and ask another question if you get stuck on something specific

Comment: @Liam it's not too broad. If you cant answer in single line of code it doesnt mean that question is too broad.

Comment: I think mobile browsers have the "scroll up more than allowed and then bounce back" behaviour already build in, so I guess you could check if the page has scrolled all the way to the bottom; if it did, steal the touchstart, touchmove and touchend events and fire your own js function to load more content.

Comment: @JonasGrumann don't lnow anything about built in behaviour. When you end up scrolling, it just stops.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a Pseudo element at the end of the list(with some height).

Now in Javascript check if the offset of this element is above the bottom of screen and scroll up to hide it (with some delay).

Also hide the scroll bar else it may look a bit weird.

Comment: Good aproach, but the trouble is that scrolling wont stop at the bottom when user scrolls regular list. I mean if you ar on top of table and swipe th page down - you will see that 'pseudo' element.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what we found is simplest, fastest solution. By now. I wont accept the answer because I don't like the solution (it works but still). I think there sholud be more elegant and native way.

First you have to detect when user stops scrolling. It meand he is in the very top o very bottom of the list that expected to have that "bounce behavior".

```
    var $selector = $('some-your-selector'); //that's the list

            var $pullDownPlaceholder = $('<div class="js-pull-placeholder js-pull-down-placeholder"/>');
            var $pullUpPlaceholder = $('<div class="js-pull-placeholder js-pull-up-placeholder"/>');
            $selector.append($pullDownPlaceholder); //we append one placeholder with 0 height at the bottom of the list
            $selector.prepend($pullUpPlaceholder); //and prepend another one at the top of the list




    //We will need initial start up points X and Y, that we wrint in data properties to use later
    $selector.on('touchstart', function (e){

                    $(this).data('YonTouchStart', e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY);
                    $(this).data('XonTouchStart', e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX);

                });

    //When user moves the selector up or down we'll try to detect he has reached bottom or top in the scroll

    $selector.on('touchmove', function (e){

                    var $this = $(this);
                    var YonTouchStart = $this.data('YonTouchStart');
                    var XonTouchStart = $this.data('XonTouchStart');
                    var YonTouchEnd = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY;
                    var XonTouchEnd = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX;

                    var diffY = YonTouchEnd - YonTouchStart;
                    var diffX = XonTouchEnd - XonTouchStart;

                    var scrollHeight = $this.prop('scrollHeight');
                    var divHeight = $this.height();
                    var scrollerEndPoint = scrollHeight - divHeight;
                    var divScrollerTop =  $this.scrollTop();

                    var initted = null;

                    //user scrolled down to the bottom!
                    if(divScrollerTop === scrollerEndPoint)
                    {
                        initted = 'bottom';
//WE will use requestAnimationFrame almost everywhere because otherwise the productivity on mobile phone can be really poor
                        requestAnimationFrame(
                            function(){
//we close upper placeholder
                                $this.find('.js-pull-up-placeholder').height(0);
                            }
                        );

                    } else if (0===divScrollerTop) {
                        initted = 'top';
                        requestAnimationFrame(
                            function(){
//if we are on top we have to make sure we close lower placeholder
                                $this.find('.js-pull-down-placeholder').height(0);
                            }
                        );
                    }

    //Now we just set height of the placeholder 

                    var height = Math.abs(diffY);
                    if (initted == 'top') {
                        requestAnimationFrame(
                            function(){
                                $this.find('.js-pull-up-placeholder').height(height);
                            }
                        );
                    } else if (initted == 'bottom'){
                        requestAnimationFrame(
                            function(){
                                $this.find('.js-pull-down-placeholder').height(height);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });



    //And finally - if user releases selector, we need to destroy placeholder
                $selector.on('touchend', function (e){

                    var $this = $(this);
                    requestAnimationFrame(
                        function(){
                            $this.find('.js-pull-placeholder').height(0);
                        }
                    );

                });
```